# Reverse array in C recursively

Tags: c, string, algorithm, recursion, reverse

Here's a part of my code, where I am trying to reverse a string recursively:

```
    char reverse[10];
    gets(reverse);
    reverseString(reverse, (strlen(reverse) - 1));
    void reverseString(char ar[], int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int temp = ar[n];
            ar[n] = *(ar);
            *(ar) = temp;
            reverseString((ar + 1), (n - 1));
        }
    }
```

When I enter the string "hello" it changes the string to "ohell". I need it to reverse the string totally to "olleh". Can someone help?

Comment: The gets() is killing me

Comment: try to make building blocks. reverse by swapping complete blocks, and once they're swapped recursively swap the internals of the block.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what is actually being replaced. You'll be surprised...

Comment: You are not stopping the recursion at the correct time.

Comment: Never use `gets`, it's not even in the latest standard anymore.

Comment: If you need a replacement for `gets`, I'll save you a Google and inform you that the common replacement is `fgets(reverse, sizeof reverse, stdin)`. If the array is dynamically created using `malloc` or `calloc`, you need a variable that retains the number of elements, which should be passed to `fgets` in place of the `sizeof` expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you swap the first and last element of the array, you should recursively
call the function with the remaining `n-2` elements (instead of `n-1`),

```
void reverseString(char ar[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp = ar[n];
        ar[n] = *(ar);
        *(ar) = temp;
        reverseString((ar + 1), (n - 2));
    }
}
```

(I have assumed that `reverseString` and `reverseAr` in your code are
actually the same functions, perhaps some copy-paste error.)

Comment: there's also an error for odd length strings that is solved in your answer, with the stop condition `n <= 0`.

Comment: @zmo: Regarding your comment to the now deleted answer: The reverse of "653421" should be "654321" and not "653421".

Comment: damn, I'm getting dyslexic on sundays :-s

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <stdio.h>

/* Function to print reverse of the passed string */
void reverse(char *str)
{
   if(*str)
   {
       reverse(str+1);
       printf("%c", *str);
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "Geeks for Geeks";
   reverse(a);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: it looks like the OP wants in place reversal of the string.